# ExtractValue mysql XML return empty instead of NULL

Tags: mysql, xml, null, isnullorempty

I tried to get a NULL value but output is always empty, i don't know if is about mysql configuration,

queries;

```
mysql> SELECT ExtractValue('
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <lista>
      <socios>
         <inscripcion xsi:nil="true"></inscripcion>
      </socios>
    </lista>','lista/socios/inscripcion') as value;
+-------+
| value |
+-------+
|       |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


mysql> SELECT ExtractValue('
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <lista>
    <socios>
      <inscripcion xsi:nil="true" />
    </socios>
  </lista>','lista/socios/inscripcion') as value;
+-------+
| value |
+-------+
|       |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

### mysql> \s

mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.37, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2

Connection id:          53
Current database:
Current user:           root@localhost
SSL:                    Not in use
Current pager:          stdout
Using outfile:          ''
Using delimiter:        ;
Server version:         5.5.37-0+wheezy1 (Debian)
Protocol version:       10
Connection:             Localhost via UNIX socket
Server characterset:    latin1
Db     characterset:    latin1
Client characterset:    utf8
Conn.  characterset:    utf8
UNIX socket:            /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Uptime:                 2 hours 21 min 33 sec

### Threads: 3  Questions: 3531  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 453  Flush tables: 1  Open tables: 135  Queries per second avg: 0.415

Comment: got same output, i dont get it at all.

Comment: how i should force to get a NULL value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [***`MySQL XML Functions Documentation`***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/xml-functions.html):

> If no matching text node is found for the expression (including the implicit /`text()`)—for whatever reason, as long as `xpath_expr` is valid, and `xml_frag` consists of elements which are properly nested and closed—an empty string is returned. No distinction is made between a match on an empty element and no match at all. This is by design.

However, you can determine whether there was actually a matching element using the following:

```
SELECT ExtractValue('
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <lista>
      <socios>
         <inscripcion xsi:nil="true"></inscripcion>
      </socios>
    </lista>', 'count(lista/socios/inscripcion)') as value;
```

Output would be:

```
+-------+
| value |
+-------+
| 1     |
+-------+
```

---

**Edit 1**:

> *got same output, i dont get it at all. how i should force to get a NULL value?*

If the returned (trimmed) string is of length zero, then you can explicitly return a `NULL`.

**Example**:

```
SELECT if( length( trim( @v:=ExtractValue( '
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <lista>
      <socios>
         <inscripcion xsi:nil="true">  </inscripcion>
      </socios>
    </lista>', '/lista/socios/inscripcion' ) ) ) = 0, NULL, @v ) as value;

+-------+
| value |
+-------+
| NULL  |
+-------+
```

You can remove using `trim` if return a string with only spaces is acceptable.

Comment: thanks, it works, but i tried to do in another way, based in you answer, i have same output with 



`code`SELECT if( length( @v:=ExtractValue( '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><lista><socios><inscripcion xsi:nil="true" /></socios></lista>', '/lista/socios/inscripcion' ) ) = 0, NULL, @v ) as value;`code`